# Looking for a NoSQL Solution for Mono

Tags: c#, mono, nosql

I'm looking for a NoSQL Database to use on Windows and Linux with C#. I prefer a solution where I can have the DB Server in my application (as Assembly ".dll"), and do not need a dedicated Server. An optional dedicated Server would be nice, though.

Native Mono support would be better than patches to existing DB solutions like http://codeofrob.com/entries/ravendb-on-mono.html

Thanks for Help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Won't MongoDB do? I believe the [official C# drivers](http://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/downloads) are hosted on Github. [Here's](http://sourcecodebean.com/archives/mongodb-c-and-mono/1408) a quickstart, too! Note that the driver has since matured and [supports LINQ](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+LINQ+Tutorial) as well.

Or did I misunderstand your question?